# How do you test authentication in API controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm writing a Rails API and am stuck trying to write controllers that will test the authentication. For instance, I have in my `PostController` `before_action :authenticate` which is

```
def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
    User.find_by(:auth_token => token)
  end
end
```

And this is my `PostsController` test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Api::PostsController, type: :controller do

  let(:valid_attributes) {
    {
      "title"                => "Post title",
      "content"              => "Post content",
      "status"               => "published"
    }
  }

  let(:invalid_attributes) {
    {
      "title"                => "",
      "content"              => "",
      "status"               => ""
    }
  }

  let(:valid_session) { {} }

  before do
    params = { session: { email: 'wagner.matos@mac.com', password: 'foobar' } }
    SessionsController.create params
    @post = Post.new({
      title: "Some title",
      content: 'Some content',
      status: "published"
    })
  end

  it "creates a new post" do
    post :create, post: @post
    expect(Post.count).to eq(1)
  end

end
```

Yet the above is failing with the following error:

```
1) Api::PostsController creates a new post
 Failure/Error: SessionsController.create params
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `create' for SessionsController:Class
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not invoke `create` action of `SessionsController` with class. Better you create user object and assign to `request.env` the same `token`. like below sample code -

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe Api::PostsController, type: :controller do
   before do          
     user = User.create( :auth_token => 'token' )
     request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Token.encode_credentials("token")
   end
end
```